# Setting permission of file using chmod command (textual and numeric representations)

Tags: linux, unix, chmod

***Question:***

***Use chmod to set the permissions of that file to:***

**• readable, writable, and executable by yourself**

**• readable and executable by the group that you belong to.**

**• readable by other users**

1) What are the chmod commands if the textual permission representation method is used?

2) What is the chmod command if the numeric permission representation method is used?

**My work:**

```
  1) chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=r students.txt  // textual permission representation     
  2) chmod 754 students.txt             // numeric permission representation
```

**Comments:** Would this answer 1) and 2) correctly? I know that my answer for 2) is correct because I am using a numeric value that I found using binary numbers so thus it is a numeric representation.

However, not sure if my answer for 1) is called "textual representation" but it sets the permission using the 'rwx' characters which does seem to be somewhat textual.

***I'm just seeking a clarification on if my logic makes sense and if my answers are correct.***

Comment: Your answers are correct however I am unclear which part you are having doubts with.

Comment: I just had doubts with the definitions of textual and numeric. Just didn't understand if these representations met the definitions. Thanks for clarifying it though.

Comment: Only one comment.  The group permissions are not the ones you belong to, but the ones **the file belongs to** (it has also a `gid` telling what group it belongs to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

geforce -

You are absolutely correct with your work. Method 1 is the textual representation of permissions for using chmod. Methof 2 is the numberical representation of permissions for using chmod.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean method 1 is textual and method 2 is numerical? Because both cant be numerical